# Can I send messages using the SIM from the same carrier as the recipient? (wildcard sending)

Tags: sms, dual-sim

Sorry guys am using two sim phone to connect to my gateway for client purchase notifications. I would like to send messages based on receiver phone number carrier. e.g if sender uses MTN number I wish to reply with MTN number, but I figured out the phone only allow the options of "default number" or "always ask" which forces me always to monitor the number to use when sending message. Is there a way I can switch the sending of the messages based on the number of a receiver (something like wildcard sending)?

Comment: I assume you mean SMS messages, so I've add that tag to your question. Feel free to [edit] the question again if I was wrong.

Comment: #Dan ya you're right. .. so far have you figured solutions or approaches?